# How to correct put return from the function into in statement

Tags: plsql

I create function that return few values into 1 varchar row.
select listagg(q'<'>' || expr || q'<'>', ',') into v_return
function return varchar2(1000).
optionally expr can be number or char.
When i select function from dual
i get normal output like:
'1','2','3'
When i try to run function like select where ... in (function)
I get "ORA-01722: invalid number"

**Can varchar return work correct for few values?**

I tried:
select listagg(q'<'>' || expr || q'<'>', ',')
select listagg(expr, q'<','>')
select listagg(expr, ',').

Comment: You cannot use the `IN` operator with a column value / expression / variable. `IN` only works with either a subquery or a *literal* list of values (the parentheses and commas have to be part of the SQL text itself, though the individual items can be columns or expressions), so using `LISTAGG` to assemble the in-list for use in the same SQL isn't going to work. Instead, you should probably just do a standard `IN` subquery against whatever table you are taking the `LISTAGG` values from.